# Data is not rendering after login, I have to refresh the page to render the data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

So, i have an Spotify API. The issue is, when I login I'm getting the token and redirecting to Dashboard page. But my component is not rendering the data as soon as i login until i refresh the page.All I see is "No Data to display" from Mainrightsection.js but when i refresh I can see the data from rendering. How can i solve it?

Also after login I'm getting "No Access Token" from SpotifyApiState.js. So my timing of rendering components is wrong i guess????

**Login page**

```
const Login = () => {

    const host = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
    const [credential, setCredential] = useState({ email: "", password: "" })
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const getToken = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`),
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                }),
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token);
            navigate('/');

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching Spotify API token:', error);
        }
    };
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: credential.email, password: credential.password }),
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        if (json.success) {
            getToken();
        }
        else {
            console.log("Invalid credentials")
        }

    }
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setCredential({ ...credential, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='flex flex-col'>
               //login form
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login
```

**SpotifyApiState.js**

```
import SpotifyApiContext from './SpotifyApiContext'
import axios from "axios";

const SpotifyApiState = (props) => {

  const [categorydata, setCategorydata] = useState([])
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const getCategories = async () => {
    if (!accessToken) {
      console.error('Access token not available yet.');
      return;
    }
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories`,
      params: {
        country: 'IN',
        offset: '0',
        limit: '10',
      },
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.request(options);
      console.log('Fetch categories data', response.data);
      setCategorydata(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error Fetching categories data', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SpotifyApiContext.Provider value={{ categorydata, getCategories }}>
      {props.children}
    </SpotifyApiContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default SpotifyApiState
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {

    return (
      <SpotifyApiState>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path='/' element={<MainDashboard />} />
          <Route exact path='/carddata' element={<CardData />} />
          <Route exact path='/mainrightsection' element={<MainRightSection />} />
        </Routes>
      </SpotifyApiState>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
  const MainDashboard = () => {
    const [showCardData, setShowCardData] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="App  text-white p-2 flex flex-col items-stretch  max-h-screen">
                <div className='flex gap-2 mb-2 flex-grow dashboard overflow-hidden'>
                    <MainSidenav />
                    <MainSection showCardData={showCardData} setShowCardData={setShowCardData} />
                </div>
                <FooterPlayer />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default MainDashboard
```

**MainRightsection**

```
const MainRightSection = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(SpotifyApiContext);
    const { categorydata, getCategories } = context;

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories();
        getAllPlaylists();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    const getplaylistID = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        getPlaylists(id);
    }
    return (
        <div className='relative z-0'>
            <div className='px-4 flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-6'>
                <section className='mb-4 w-full'>
                    <div className='pt-6'>
                        <Swiper slidesPerView={2} spaceBetween={10} breakpoints={breakpoints}>
                            {!categorydata || !categorydata.categories ? (
                                <div className='text-center text-2xl'>
                                    No Data to display yet ...
                                </div>
                            ) :
                                (
                                    categorydata.categories.items.map((items, index) => {
                                        return <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                                            <CategoryCard icon={items.icons} item={items} />
                                        </SwiperSlide>
                                    })
                                )
                            }
                        </Swiper>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainRightSection
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your `Login` component doesn't change the context (`SpotifyApiContext`), you only change the `localStorage` on successful login. Either call `getCategories` inside the `Login` component or add an event listener for `localStorage` changes in the context and make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Its working now. Im sending token as a props from login to spotifyapistate. So far its working now.